# Hide element with JavaScript based in IP-Address

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide an element based on an IP-address.

With this script I can write out the IP-adress in the DOM:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("Your IP is :", userip)</script>
```

How Do I target this to remove the element below based on a specific IP-address?

Comment: i think this: `if(userip == "127.0.0.1"){//remove your elements}` should work.

Comment: Do note that this system is entirely unreliable for any real-world uses. IP can very easily be spoofed, client-based protection can also easily be bypassed.

Comment: @vlaz good point, but differentiating ip addresses may improve UX by delivering different contents on the upside.

Comment: @DanielCheung also not a good idea to do it in JS client-side. Doing either on the server is way easier - first of all, you don't have to use a workaround to find the IP. That one is a big give away that doing this client-side is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use document ready and check the ip. IF it matches the condition do your stuff

```
    var ip=['123.123.123','111.111.11']
     $(document).ready(function () {
if(ip.indexOf(userip)!=-1)
{ your  code here
}
});
```